# Holomorphic functions bounded by other holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Here is a problem I encountered while studying old comp problems for a final.

Suppose that $f(z)$ is an entire holomorphic function satisfying $|f(z)| \leq |\cos(z)|$ for every $z$. Show that $f(z)$ is a constant multiple of $\cos(z)$.

The basic strategy is to use Louiville's Theorem. We want to define $g(z) = f(z)/\cos(z)$, and then use the fact that $|g| \leq 1$ everywhere. This seems like the way to go, because then $g$ is constant, so $f$ is a multiple of $\cos$.

The problem is that Louiville's Theorem does not apply to $g$, since whenever the cosine function is $0$, this function is not defined. A natural thing to do is to hope that the singularities at the zeros are removable, and then to just extend $g$ at those isolated points.

My thought was that since $f$ is bounded by cosine, that the quotient was bounded in a neighborhood of the singularity, and so is removable by  the theorem of Riemann... Maybe this is not completely obvious though.

So my question is two-fold. First, is this line of reasoning okay so far? Second, can a technique like this be applied in general, when one entire function is bounded by another?

Comment: Since $|g|\leq1$ everywhere, the singularities are removable as you said. Another way of seeing this is $|f(z)|\leq|\cos(z)|$ implies that $f$ has a zero at each of cosine's zeros, and to at least the same multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and Yes.

A priori, the singularities of $g$ at zeroes of $\cos$ can be removable or poles or essential. In the latter two cases, $g$ would not be bounded in a (punctured) disk around that point, but it certainly is.

Comment: Great, this is what I was thinking. I don't have a good intuition about what happens with essential singularities, so I just wanted to make sure my reasoning was OK. Thank you!